# Unpack an JSON nested objects with unknown items in ADF

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am pulling a dataset from a vendors API that returns a JSON file containing nested objects and having some difficulty in extracting the data. My tools are Azure Data Factory (ADF) and SQL JSON commands. I have tried both with no joy.

Regarding the file structure - it is in the form of a questionnaire with different numbers of questions and each question has a number that does not follow a pattern. So think of a repeating record with one record for each question and this record having the same structure for each question and containing the question text and answer.

I want to pull all the questions and pivot them to have one SQL record per question.  The problem is the item number that I can't source so I think a wildcard is needed so I always get all the records

[Example of the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxXa4.gif)

I have tried both ADF and SQL JSON but both don't seem to cater for the wildcard ie return all the values no mater what they are. I can get the data if I hard code the first number but I don't know the sequence and there are different questionnaires with different numbers and questions. As this is an external vendor it is difficult to get help from them.

Possibly it is impossible to do this in ADF or SQL - if so can you recommend an alternate tool [enter

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please paste in as text only. Please show what code you tried so far.

Comment: Use openjson in the edge form, ie select * from openjson(json_column, '$.responses') x  . This way you get two columns key, value back where key is the number thing